# strtolower(trim()) == strtolower(trim()) is slow

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking at some code that processes about 7k items in a CSV.  The CSV importer checks for duplicates and part of that process is for each row it checks all of the other rows that have been processed for duplicates.  This means it does something like...

```
foreach ($users as $possibleDuplicate) {
    if (strtolower(trim($user->first_name)) == strtolower(trim($possibleDuplicate->first_name)) && strtolower(trim($user->last_name)) == strtolower(trim($possibleDuplicate->last_name))) {

    }
}
```

Ignore the terrible execution ideas put into place on this script (I didn't write it).  The `strtolower(trim())` seem to be making quite a performance hit on my import.  I've been looking for a much  more efficient and faster replacement.  I haven't done any performance tests yet, but plan to tomorrow.  I was hoping someone here might be able to shed some light on some information they already have on methods that might be faster like `preg_match()`.

**Update:**  I'm not looking to increase the performance of this loop, I recognize that moving methods outside of the foreach will significantly improve performance.

Comment: I can tell you that regex will definitely be slower than `strtolower`

Comment: Maybe use [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) (case insensitive string comparison)?

Comment: Are you running them multiple times through those functions? If so, you could process them all and store them in a map and then retrieve from there, or do it lazily as you find values not existing in the map.

Comment: @alex Yes, they are all throughout this importer... which may be the root cause.

Comment: I found this article: http://www.alwaysgetbetter.com/blog/2013/09/29/comparing-strtolower-strcasecmp-caseinsensitive-string-checking-php/ maybe it is helpful and `strcasecmp` is an alternative. Additional you should try to use the `===` operator since both are strings and the comparison is maybe faster with that.

Comment: You should definitely just run through all of the users and parse `strtolower(trim())` once for each item, then going back through to compare.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/triple-equals-vs-twice-equals just wanted to add this link after @Flixer suggested it. It really makes a sense to use triple **===** to speed up comparison.

Comment: You could of course also build in array with `$seen[strtolower(trim($user->first_name))][strtolower(trim($user->first_name))]`, and just check with `isset()`  for subsequent user whether those exist. I think the problem is the way the check is now, I suspect 7k rows would [result in `(7000 * (7000 + 1))/2 = 24,503,500 `](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_⋯) times this is executed, am I right there?

Comment: In other words, can we see more of the code _how_ this is used? We might be optimizing the wrong thing ;)

Comment: Are you certain you've done profiling to pinpoint the execution bottleneck on this function calls and not some external database or service interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move parts that don't vary outside of the loop:

and maybe put the last_name test before the first name test (to fail faster if everybody has the first name "John", however everybody can have "McGuire" as last name)

```
$userFirstNameLower = strtolower(trim($user->first_name));
$userLastNameLower = strtolower(trim($user->last_name));
foreach ($users as $possibleDuplicate) {
    if ( $userLastNameLower == strtolower(trim($possibleDuplicate->last_name)) && $userFirstNameLower == strtolower(trim($possibleDuplicate->first_name))) {

    }
}
```